# Problem when resizing and saving a turtle screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

So I could save a big drawing and see its full size in an image visualizer, I resized my turtle window bigger then my monitor size. But the saved image is not being resized, so the drawing is being truncated:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import random

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1200, height=2700, startx=None, starty=None)
t = Turtle(visible=False)
t.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

t2 = Turtle(visible=False)
t2.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

t3 = Turtle(visible=False)
t3.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience


def got(x, y, d):  # to use goto more easily
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()
    t.seth(d)


def flatoval(r):  # Horizontal Oval
    t.right(45)
    for loop in range(2):
        t.circle(r, 90)
        t.circle(r / 2, 90)


got(0, -200, 0)


def elipse(r, a, b, c):
    for extent in range(9):
        rnd = random.randint(1, 20)
        # if extent == 0 or extent == 3 or extent == 6 :
        # t.color('red')
        # if extent == 1 or extent == 4 or extent == 7 :
        # t.color('yellow')
        # if extent == 2 or extent == 5 or extent == 8 :
        # t.color('blue')

        t.circle(r, 10)

        heading = t.heading()

        if extent == 0 or extent == 1 or extent == 2:
            # t.color('green')
            t.setheading(0)
            t.forward(rnd)
            t.forward(a)
            t.backward(rnd)
            t.forward(c)

        t.setheading(heading)


def canais(x, y, d, egnar):
    for tog in range(egnar):
        got(x, y, d)

        elipse(100, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(50, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(100, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(50, 0, 0, 0)
        d = d + 10
        elipse(200, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(100, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(200, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(100, 0, 0, 0)

        elipse(300, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(200, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(300, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(200, 0, 0, 0)


canais(0, -100, 0, 40)

ts = t.getscreen()

ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="canais_organizados_separadamente.eps")
```

I also tried this change:

```
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1200, height=2700, startx=None, starty=None)
```

in place of:

```
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(400, 500)
```

Truncated image:

[image: cutted image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the tkinter canvas `postscript()` method only captures the *visible* portion of the canvas.  You need to tell it, via the `width` and `height` arguments, whether you want more than that.  Below is your code reworked with that fix and several others to improve the performance and/or simplify the logic:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

def got(x, y, d):  # to use goto more easily
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setheading(d)

def flatoval(r):  # Horizontal Oval
    turtle.right(45)

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.circle(r, 90)
        turtle.circle(r / 2, 90)

def elipse(r, a, b, c):
    for extent in range(9):
        rnd = randint(1, 20)

        turtle.circle(r, 10)

        heading = turtle.heading()

        if extent <= 2:
            turtle.setheading(0)
            turtle.forward(rnd)
            turtle.forward(a)
            turtle.backward(rnd)
            turtle.forward(c)

        turtle.setheading(heading)

def canais(x, y, d, egnar):
    for _ in range(egnar):
        got(x, y, d)

        elipse(100, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(50, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(100, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(50, 0, 0, 0)

        elipse(200, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(100, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(200, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(100, 0, 0, 0)

        elipse(300, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(200, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(300, 0, 0, 0)
        elipse(200, 0, 0, 0)

        d += 10

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1200, 1200)

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

got(0, -200, 0)

screen.tracer(False)
canais(0, -100, 0, 36)
screen.tracer(True)

canvas = screen.getcanvas()

canvas.postscript(file="canais_organizados_separadamente.eps", width=1200, height=1200)
```

[image]