# Saving a large turtle graphics image from the entire canvas, not just the window

Tags: python, image, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas, postscript

After looking for answers all around, I find lots of help and guidance on how to save a file either using turtle screen or tkinter canvas mixed with the turtle module. I'm drawing a large image and the windows size is fine and scrollable, letting me see the entire image. But when I try to save the image to postscript, I only get the window view, not the entire canvas. Cannot find out how to proceed, any tips?

There might be an answer in [How can I convert canvas content to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image) but I cannot see how to connect tkinter with turtle. Can someone elaborate on that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert canvas content to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your issue, and I'm sure we'd be happy to help.

Comment: There might be an answer in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image] but I cannot see how to connect tkinter with turtle. Can someone elaborate on that?

Comment: I don't believe the multiply cited answer deals with this issue.  By default, the `postscript()` method only captures the visible portion of the canvas. You need to tell it you want more. See my earlier [answer regarding this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669350/5771269).

Comment: Hi @cdlane, thanks that helped me indirectly. I had used the width/height arguments in postcript, but what I needed was to tell turtle to goto a better starting position as well. turtle.goto() :) Thanks, I now see the whole drawing. Feel free to post this as an answer.